# Trying to install SpatiaLite 4.3 with SQLite 3.8 on Windows 7

Tags: spatialite, sqlite, windows-7

I'm new to the open-source GIS database world, and am trying to have SpatiaLite installed on my Windows 7 machine.

I downloaded SQLite 3.8.2 and unpacked the 3 files in a newly created folder c:\Program Files\SQLite. I added the folder to the PATH env variable, and managed to get that going.

To install SpatiaLite, I went to webpage https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/index, downloaded libspatialite-4.1.1.zip , which I believe is the latest SpatiaLite version for Windows. I unpacked this zip-file into the aforementioned SQLite folder, and then tried to run  .load 'SpatiaLite.dll' from the SQLite prompt. But this gives me an error.

Investigation shows that there is no such thing as 'SpatiaLite.dll', even though I thought I was just following the download and install instructions.

Where am I getting wrong?

Comment: Try to download from [Index of /gaia-sins/windows-bin-x86](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-x86/) or [Index of /gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-amd64/)

Comment: You should also include the exact error message if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you downloaded libspatialite-4.1.1.zip, you downloaded the source code. That will work, but you'd need to [build it first](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/mingw_how_to.html). From your description, I guess that didn't happen.

Instead, you probably want to download packages that are already built. If you have a 32 bit build, use:
http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/windows-bin-x86/